# group (gather) items of an object

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i have a List of an Object, with the following characteristics:

```
Class Object{
  String gender;
  String state;
  int quantity;
  int Salary;
}

List<Object> myList=new ArrayList<Object>;
```

As input of the List, i have the following:

[image]

and as Output, i want to keep only one occurrence of the object with the same gender and the same state, in the same time sum the quantity and the salsary correspanding, like the following:

[image]

my question is how can i loop through myList, find objects with the same gender and the same state,keep only one occurence of them, and sum the quantity and the salary correspanding ??

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  What have you tried so far, and how does it come up short?

Comment: @ScottHunter i have edited the post, do you understand for now ??

Comment: you need a `for` loop...

Comment: can you be more specific please ?? @scrappedcola

Comment: for(Object a: MyList){
   
   //treatement
  }
i don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

First off, I renamed your class to MyObject as Object is the base Java class. Now for the rest of it - You can use a pseudo-index made out of the gender and state combinations you have already found and sum up the values for the rest of the list as follows:

```
Class MyObject{
  String gender;
  String state;
  int quantity;
  int Salary;
}

List<MyObject> myList=new ArrayList<MyObject>();
List<String> stateAndGender = new ArrayList<String>();
List<MyObject> finalList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
// add objects here
for(MyObject mO : myList){
    String s = mO.getGender();
    s+="," + mO.getState();
    if(stateAndGender.indexOf(s)==-1)
    {
        MyObject fO = new MyObject();
        fO.setGender(mO.getGender());
        fO.setState(mO.getState());
        stateAndGender.add(s);
        int Qua = mO.getQuantity();
        int Sal = mO.getSalary();
        for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(String t = myList.get(i).getGender()+","+myList.get(i).getGender() == s)
            Qua += myList.get(i).getQuantity();
            Sal += myList.get(i).getSalary();
        }
        fO.setQuantity(Qua);
        fO.setSalary(Sal);
        finalList.add(fO);
    }
}
// Then return finalList
```

The above code assumes you have proper getters for the fields of the class you have created and your gender and state do not contain commas, otherwise you will need to tweak the code.

UPDATE: Now you get a list of the MyObject type with the proper values as you requested! It is not the original one, though, but the one called `finalList`.

Comment: as output i need myList,not 3 lists as the above

Comment: @hamzaspecter ok, I'll add a workaround, gimme a minute!